What is the smallest size for a heavy stable galaxy?
As Douglas Adams said, Space is big. This galaxy alone is 100,000 light-years in diameter. The nearest Solar System is over 4 light-years away. But what if space within a galaxy was less big?
I'm creating a new galaxy for my story. This galaxy has similar mass and objects to the Milky Way, but is much smaller. Instead, this galaxy only has a diameter of 10 light-years. This galaxy is now far more dense than any known galaxy, but still has a density far below 1 kg/m^3.
Could a galaxy that is much more compact be stable and contain all the astronomical objects in the current Milky Way galaxy? Or is there a fundamental limit that forces galaxy to have extremely low densities?

Such a galaxy may last for a while - long enough for a good story - were it initially engineered rather than naturally formed.

Our Milky way is 100k light years in diameter, and the average distance between close stars is 5 light years.
If you scale down the diameter to 10 light years, thus 10 thousand times, the average star distance will be 0.0005 light years or a bit less than 4.5 light hours.
That is closer than the distance between Pluto and the Sun, and I don't need a PhD in astrophysics to tell that having stars that close will result either in massive slingshots throwing around cosmic bodies in the neighborhood, for the joy of nearby galaxies, or some big crunch quickly creating a black hole.

In support of this, a galaxy requies time to form, but all the mass of all the stars and planets in proximity at the outset. What this means is that such a galaxy would be far more likely to form a single supermassive black hole than an entire Milky Way galaxy worth of individual stars.

This answer is right in that 10 ly wide galaxy would not be stable at all (or stable in a black hole), but it doesn't answer the actual question about how much smaller it could be. I don't think an answer just saying 10 ly won't work is a suitable response to the question of "What is the smallest size for a heavy stable galaxy?"

I would also like to address the question in the title. If we use Proxima Centauri as an example, we can extrapolate a plausible limit.

Proxima Centauri, also (though less frequently) called Alpha Centauri C, is much farther away (between 4300 and 13,000 AU) from α Cen AB, and orbits the central pair with a period of 547,000 (+66,000/-40,000) years.[39]

Star System
At its periapsis, Proxima is about 0.07 light years away from the core binary system. We know this is a stable system that may even have habitable candidates. If we massage the number down to 0.05, then we get a factor of 100 between the actual average 5 light years distance between stars. That would put your super dense milky way at 1000 light years across.
Being this close, the gravitational relationship between the stars would turn into (what I would guess to be) an unstable n-body problem, but it is conceivable.
